# Exception Handling in Spring AMQP MessagePostProcessor

Tags: spring-amqp, spring-rabbit

I have written a MessagePostProcessor which gets called before any consumer onMessage is called.

Now if any exception occurs in my MessagePostProcessor i need to catch the exception otherwise the message will get infinitely requed in Rabbitmq server Q getting back to and fro again. 
So fix this problem i need to catch an exception in my component MessagePostProcessor , But because of that the consumers are not getting correct problem for the issue at their end.

What is best practice of handling such scenarios.

Pseudo MessagePostProcessor

```
@Service 
public class TestPostProcessor implements MessagePostProcessor {

    /**
 * {@inheritDoc}
 */
@Override
public Message postProcessMessage(Message message) {
    try {
        // some logic
    } catch (Exception exception) {
        // log error
    }
    return message;
}
```

}

Answer (score 2):

> But because of that the consumers are not getting correct problem for the issue at their end.

I am not sure what you mean by that.

If the post processor can't process the message for some reason, you can throw an `AmqpRejectAndDontRequeuException` and the message will be discarded (or routed to a DLX/DLQ if so configured).

If you want the message to be passed to the consumer, but somehow communicate the problem to the consumer, you can return a completely new `Message`, or add some data to the headers.

```
message.getMessageProperties().getHeaders().set("badMessageInfo", ...);
```